# Is it possible to comment objects in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, comments, google-bigquery

Is it possible to comment tables, columns, etc. in Google BigQuery? For example PostgreSQL has the `comment` command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-comment.html.

If so, are there any system tables from which these comments can be retrieved via a SQL interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: Yes

Question 2: No

Through the API you can add comments to datasets, tables, and fields. You can retrieve comments through the API too, but not through a SQL interface.

You can also see and edit annotations through the web UI (that uses the API to do so).

See the API docs:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

(note the 'description' field for the table and its fields)

Comment: Thanks! Can you link to the relevant part of the docs and I'll accept this?

Comment: The API docs for comments are spread on each object, I linked on the answer to the table and its fields: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

Comment: Would be interesting if this API would be exposed as stored procedures in some system catalog similar to SQL Server's `sp_rename`... A SQL API would be even better, but any API available to a SQL client would do. Codd's Rules and such...

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong/outdated for the second question.

You can read the `description` of a column by retrieving information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`

Example query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `my-project.mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
```

This yields the following columns:

- table_catalog
- table_schema
- table_name
- column_name
- field_path
- data_type
- **description**